# Fetching Private Key Bytes from Windows Certificate Store

Tags: windows, certificate

I have an PFX Certificate file containing both Client Certificate and Private Key. Then I have imported this pfx file in Windows Personal Certificate Store.

Now I need to extract the certificate and Private Key bytes and passed to an openssl api.

I am able to extract the Certificate but not able to extract the private key bytes in Plain Text using windows Crypto API's .

I have searched for it but not got exactly what I need. So please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

## Use "Jailbreak"

The *"non exportable"* attribute can be overridden with [NCC's "Jailbreak"](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/resources/jailbreak/).

Comment: Thanks for this. But i have to do this Programmatically

Comment: I see. You're trying to override an explicit *"don't do this"* flag in Windows. I don't think there is an official API for this. What you could do is: (a) force export via jailbreak. (b) delete cert/privkey from Windows store. (c) reimport to store but this time with the *"mark as non-exportable"* attribute not set.